# Does there exist a k-Sassy number with $2^{k-1}$ positive divisors?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

For $k \in [2, \infty)\cap \Bbb{Z}$, we say a *k-sassy* number is a positive integer $n$ such that no divisor $d$ of $n$ satisfies

$1 < d \le \sqrt[k]{n}$

It is not too difficult to see that a k-sassy number cannot have more than $2^{k-1}$ positive divisors (proof: Let $n$ be k-sassy number, and write $n$ as a product of primes $p_1p_2...p_m$ with $p_1 \le p_2 \le ... \le p_m$. If $m \ge k$ then $p_1 \le \sqrt[k]{n}$, contrary to hypothesis. So $m \le k - 1$, and since each divisor of n is a product of a subset of the $p_i$, $n$ has no more than $2^{k - 1}$ positive divisors.

The question is, is it true that for every $k \ge 2$, there exists a k-Sassy number with $2^{k-1}$ positive divisors?

Comment: To answer this question positive it is enough that for every $k\ge 2$, we can find $k-1$ prime numbers $p:=p_1<p_2<\cdots <p_{k-1}=:q$ such that $p^k>q^{k-1}$ holds. In this case $p_1\cdots p_{k-1}$ is a squarefree $k$-sassy number with $k-1$ prime factors, hence $2^{k-1}$ divisors. It should be not too difficult to show, that for primes large enough this can be satisfied for every $k\ge 2$.